# How can I have the user set the amount of time they want on a timer app in android?

Tags: android, xml, timer

beginner here with a question. I'm trying to build a timer app for a friend, and am aware of hander.postDelayed to set a timer for a specified amount of time. However I was wondering if there was a way to let the user decided how much time they want to countdown from, and if so, let them choose through the XML. I appreciate any help and hope this is a clear enough question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html) and Timer and pass in the amount of time from the xml file.